# What exactly is Beta in the Twitter Breakout Detection Algorithm?

Tags: r, change-point, anomaly-detection

I have been going through the R implementation of the EDM algorithm, Twitter Breakout Detection ([here](https://github.com/twitter/BreakoutDetection)) and also the corresponding paper ([here](https://courses.cit.cornell.edu/nj89/docs/edm.pdf)) and I'm not really understanding the concept of 'Beta' which they accept as input for multiple breakout detection; It isn't mentioned in the paper as far as I could see.
In one of the description of the code they say:

"A real numbered constant used to further control the amount of penalization. This is the default form of penalization, if neither (or both) beta or (and) percent are supplied this argument will be used. The default value is beta=0.008."

I don't really understand. What exactly is being penalized? what does Beta actually constitute? How would one decide a Beta value for given data?

Comment: Would it be possible to provide more background from the paper?